# Update con orm django

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

Estructura del Modelo:

```
nombre
apellido
fecha_inicio
fecha_fin
estado
fecha_actual = fecha_de_hoy
```

Como hacer la siguiente consulta con Django (`QuerySet`):

```
UPDATE usuarios_alumnos SET estado = False WHERE fecha_actual < fecha_fin
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo seria de la siguiente manera:

```
from django.db.models import F

MyModel.objects.filter(fecha_actual__lt = F('fecha_fin')).update(estado = False)
```

Las [`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) expresiones hacen referencia al valor de un campo.

Con `__lt` hace referencia a `<` por así decirlo, `__gt` seria `>`, hay mas de ellas por ejemplo, `__lte`, etc. Para mas información sobre el tema [visita la documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#gt).

Espero haberte ayudado.